# Identify the buffered bounds of a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas

Given a [Geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) [GeoDataFrame](http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html#geodataframe), I would like to extract the total bounds of the GeoDataFrame, buffered by `n` units.

With [`gdf.geometry.total_bounds`](http://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=total_bounds#GeoSeries.total_bounds), I can access the non-buffered bounds of the combined geometries in the entire DataFrame. One method I have in mind is to take these bounds, convert them to a Shapely polygon, and then buffer that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the approach you mention (creating a Polygon from the total bounds and then buffer that) is indeed the best way to do this. To do the conversion, you can use the `shapely.geometry.box` convenience function:

```
In [21]: s = geopandas.GeoSeries([Point(0,0), Point(0,5), Point(3,3)])

In [22]: s
Out[22]: 
0    POINT (0 0)
1    POINT (0 5)
2    POINT (3 3)
dtype: object

In [23]: s.total_bounds
Out[23]: (0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 5.0)

In [24]: import shapely.geometry

In [25]: shapely.geometry.box(*s.total_bounds)
Out[25]: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7fac100d25f8>

In [26]: print(shapely.geometry.box(*s.total_bounds))
POLYGON ((3 0, 3 5, 0 5, 0 0, 3 0))

In [27]: shapely.geometry.box(*s.total_bounds).buffer(3)
Out[27]: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7fac10041a90>

In [28]: shapely.geometry.box(*s.total_bounds).buffer(3).bounds
Out[28]: (-3.0, -3.0, 6.0, 8.0)
```

Alternatively (but not sure if this will always give the exact same result), you could also first combine the object into one using `cascaded_union`, buffer that and then take the bounds:

```
In [33]: s.cascaded_union
Out[33]: <shapely.geometry.multipoint.MultiPoint at 0x7fac100cd278>

In [34]: s.cascaded_union.buffer(3)
Out[34]: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7fac100cd048>

In [35]: s.cascaded_union.buffer(3).bounds
Out[35]: (-3.0, -3.0, 6.0, 8.0)
```

Comment: Terrific - thanks! I had not thought to use the `shapely.geometry.box` method.